# How to make multilingual Not-Found page in NextJS with App Router?

Tags: typescript, next.js, internationalization

in my project im using NextJS Internationalization based on docs. Main problem is I can't use params to define my site language based on url because Not-Found doesnt't accept any props.

I also want to avoid using third party libraries such as next-intl ect.

Below is my code

*Error404.tsx*

```
import { getDictionary } from "@/lib/dictionary";
import { Locale } from "@root/i18n.config";

import BigText from "@/components/BigText";
import Button from "@/components/Button";
import Heading from "@/components/Heading";

import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Error404() {
  // Should get the language from the URL but it't not possible with params here
  const lang = "en" as Locale;
  const dict = await getDictionary(lang);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center items-center h-full">
      <BigText text={dict.page.error[404].heading} />
      <Heading text={dict.page.error[404].title} />
      <Link href={`/${lang}`}>
        <Button text={dict.button.homePage} />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*not-found.tsx*

```
import Error404 from "@/routes/Error404";

export default function NotFound() {
  return <Error404 />;
}
```

Thank you!